# Calculate sum of row but its initial row number and row count

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

Let's say I have a column of numbers:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Is there a formula that can calculate sum of numbers starting from `n`-th row and adding to the sum `k` numbers, for example start from 4th row and add 3 numbers down the row, i.e. PartialSum(4, 3) would be 4 + 5 + 6 = 15

BTW I can't use App Script as now it has some type of error `Error code RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED.` and in general I have had issue of stabile work with App Script before too.

Comment: About `Error code RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED`, I thought that this might be the same issue reported at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/245673556 . Also, I have confirmed it. In this case, as the current workaround, when you use the existing (old) Google Apps Script project that has already been created before yesterday, the script can be used. I would like to believe that this will be resolved soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula:

```
 = SUM( OFFSEET( initialCellName, 0, 0, numberOfElementsInColumn, 0) )
```

Example add 7 elements starting from `A5` cell:

```
= SUM( OFFSEET( A5, 0, 0, 7, 0) )
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) mentioned, the error code when using Google Apps Script was just a temporary bug that seems to be solved at this moment.

Now, I can think of 2 possible solutions for this using custom functions:

#### Solution 1

If your data follows a specific numeric order one by one just like the example provided in the post, you may want to consider using the following code:

```
function PartialSum(n, k) {
  let sum = n;
  for(let i=1; i<k; i++)
  {
    sum = sum + n + i;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

#### Solution 2

If your data does not follow any particular order and you just want to sum a specific number of rows that follow the row you select, then you can use:

```
function PartialSum(n, k) {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let r = ss.getRange(n, 1); // Set column 1 as default (change it as needed)
  let sum = n;
  for(let i=1; i<k; i++)
  {
    let val = ss.getRange(n + i, 1).getValue();
    sum = sum + val;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)